# What is the most compact design of down-shifting double-pistons?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

It is often useful to stack pistons to shift blocks by more than one space.
As an extended piston can not be moved, the timing of the corresponding redstone circuit is of crucial importance.
Additionally, for the construction of larger gates, you have to line up several of these double extenders.

What is the most compact design of down-shifting double-pistons in a row?

Comment: The best way is to activate the first row with some repeaters to make it stay active longer and activate the second row. With right timing the second row will open and close before the first one closes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## There is none

There is a big stonking problem with the double-extender. It doesn't work vertically. At least not, if you want multiple of them after one another.

In order to line up the pistons, only one side may be used to power blocks adjacent to the pistons. So, let's look at what our redstone has to do when, and where it can do it.

For a down-pushing double-extender to work, we need to take a look at the following schematic:

[image: State 0]

In order to "close the gate", we need to **extend** the **upper piston** first, by powering the **top block**:

[image: State 1]

Then, we **extend** the **lower piston**, by powering the **bottom block**:

[image: State 2]

With this, the double-extender is fully extended. Now we need to pull it back in. For that, we first **retract** the **lower piston** by powering down the **bottom block**:

[image: State 3]

Now, **retract** the **upper piston** by powering down the **top block**:

[image: State 4]

**Ooops! Now we have a floating block.**

To fix that, we need to **extend and retract** the **lower piston** again, by powering the **middle block**:

[image: State 5]
[image: State 6]

Good, now we have the theory down.

In practice, this cannot be done on just one side (which is the requirement for having multiple of them in a line). It is impossible to power all three layers individually at these distinct times, because redstone takes up a vertical air block.

A condensed one-sided Double Extender only works horizontally (as taken from [Minecraftwiki.net](https://minecraft.wiki/w/File:Double_extender_off.png):

[image: Horizontal Double-Extender (layout courtesy Minecraftwiki.net)]

Vertical double-extenders only work with powering from multiple sides. For that purpose, I have also built an upside-down version of this vertical double-extender (again) from [Minecraftwiki.net](https://minecraft.wiki/w/File:Vertical_Double_Extender.png):

[image: working Vertical Double Extender (layout courtesy Minecraftwiki.net)]
[image: working Vertical Double Extender (layout courtesy Minecraftwiki.net)]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and well-illustrated answer! Are there alternative approaches through the introduction of the new redstone blocks?

Comment: @jeppi Any time. As far as I can tell, the new blocks can't help here either, as the core problem (a circuit needs two blocks of height, block and redstone wire) still persists.